# Relation between node to other nodes in a graph

Tags: graph, social-networking, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, analysis

I am simulating a system and in this system there are number of variables that affect each other. Despite what or how the effect is, I am presenting this as an undirected, weighted graph where vertices represent these variables and the edges have weights which represent the level of relation between two variables (higher value means higher relation). In my simulation, I want to choose a node at random (say **v**), and check the level of relation between node v and other predefined nodes (say **u1, u2, and u3**) in the network. For instance, if node **v** is strongly associated with all of the predefined nodes, then it will get a higher score than the one which is less associated with them.
My question is, if I got the level of association between node **v** and each node from the predefined nodes (**u1**, **u2**, and **u3**) individually and then sum them up. i.e. if function f calculates the level of association:

> AssociationOf(v) = f(v,u1) + f(v, u2) + f(v, u3)

Do you think that this is the right way to do it, given that it is important that the score should reflect the level of association between node **v** and all predefined nodes TOGETHER? And by together I mean the score needs to reflect the association between node **v** w.r.t ***u1 AND u2 AND u3*** (and not u1 OR u2 OR u3).

I hope that it was clear
Thank you

Comment: @amit Could you please have a look at this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, "weights which represent the level of relation between two variables (higher value means higher relation)", I think your function already satisfy that constraint.. I don't see any issue, according to your topology and constraint.

Comment: Assume that f(v,u1)=0; i.e. there is no relation between v and u1. In this case the obtained score from the function reflects only the association between v and (u2 and u3), but not all of them. The main point is to get a way where all of the predefined nodes should be part of the calculation. I link this to logical AND and OR in programming. With logical AND, all statements should satisfy to be true while with logical OR one statement is enough to get a true.

Comment: I kinda get your idea, however let me ask you this example.

E.g. A - B = 0, A - D = 5, A - C = 5, B - C = 10. I believe C will have the highest score, but between A and B, which one of them will get higher score ?

Comment: Now, your example is missing the predefined node(s) (the node that we refer to in calculating the level of association). Let's assume that the predefined node is C. Now we need to calculate the level of association between node C and each node in the graph (for instance, this will tell us how node A is related to C). If we calculate for each node (i.e. A, B, and D) we will see that node B is more associated to C, then A, and lastly D. In this case, answering your question it will be "B should have higher score" (it has stronger edge weight to C).

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm a noob or misunderstood your explanation.. As I know, people usually represent a graph as a matrix. By doing so, you can find the value of edges that are connected to a specific node. Finally, you can find the edge that has the highest value for each node, as in my example you can tell that B is more associated to C, than others. Sorry, if I'm making this more complicated..